# Is it possible to create SOAP service with .net core 5.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, web-services, wcf, unix, soap

I have an WCF application with SOAP service that need to be migrated to .net core to be able to run on unix, and not only on IIS as it does now. However the only example I found was to rewrite the application on .net core 2.2 whis is not supported any longer.
Any advice of how to proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to create SOAP service with .net core 5.0?

You can create an ASP.NET Web Application(.NET Framework) to create a SOAP Webservice, then create an asp.net core 5.0 application and call the SOAP service.

Besides, you can also try to use [SoapCore package](https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore) in the asp.net core 5.0 application, then create the SOAP service. You can refer the [SoapCore Getting Started](https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore#getting-started) or search "create soap web service in dotnet core" using Google, there have multiple tutorials about using SoapCore, you can check them.